# linq to sql relationships

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq

The code below displays sales orders related to a particular address. The problem is that when I bind this list to a datagrid the list contains the AddressID. I want it to display the related addressName from the address table.
I am not sure how to get the address name from the Address table using the AddressID in the SalesOrders table.

```
PiDbEntities ctx = new PiDbEntities();    
var q = (from s in ctx.SalesOrders
        orderby s.SalesOrderID
        where s.AddressID == Address2.AddressID
        select s).ToList();
    SalesOrderList = q;
```

Comment: I don't think the address name is in the SaleOrders table.  It must be in another table to you need to join the table with the address name to your current query.

Answer (score 0):

```
PiDbEntities ctx = new PiDbEntities();    
var q = (from s in ctx.SalesOrders
         join a in Address ON s.AddressID equals a.AddressID
         orderby s.SalesOrderID
         select new {s.Order, S.Qutity, a.AdderssName}).ToList();
SalesOrderList = q;
```

Comment: Only if SalesOrderList is a dynamic type.

Comment: Thanks for that jdweng. I am getting an error about SalesOrderList not being dynamic. Would you mind expanding on this? `public List<SalesOrder> SalesOrderList
        {
            get { return (List<SalesOrder>)(GetValue(SalesOrderListProperty)); }
            set { SetValue(SalesOrderListProperty, value); }
        }`